# Laravel Elixir Setup Warnings

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, npm, laravel-elixir

I'm trying to setup Elexir in Laravel but when I do a npm install I get these warning, what is happening?

> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
>   npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.8

Comment: better to ask on serverfult

Answer (score 0):

The [fsevents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents) module is not meant to be installed on Windows. One of the modules probably has a shrinkwrap file generated on an OS X machine. You can view this [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2679) for more information.

It's an optional dependency so it won't affect the application.